# ajax requests in IE 8 +

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

Is there any way to see AJAX requests like in FireBug for Firefox? I am interested in what was posted and the response/html returned.

I tried developer tools' profiling and debugging. I didn't see any place where it shows this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press F-12, click NETWORK tab.

Comment: You're right. I use IE9 in 8-mode. Try Fiddler - it will snoop all your HTTP traffic. http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: winInet info shows what is being passed. I will have to see if it shows the response to see if an ajax requests failed due to some server error.